# getting todo.sh to sort due items first, then by priority

Tags: sorting, date, priority, addons

How can I get todo.sh to put items that are `due:` today first, then after that sort the normal way (A-Z priority then everything else)?

There's [this solution](http://www.ericlee.info/blog/?p=849), but then you lose A-Z priority and have only "high priority" or "not" (unless you want to start memorizing the character order of punctuation...and either way you still lose the built-in colour coding.)

The `mit` add-on *only* shows by `due:` and ignores priority.

(What am I missing, here?  Isn't this a pretty common way of organizing things?  Deadlines first, priorities for everything else?)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Tips and Tricks](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks) section of the documentation you can define the `TODOTXT_SORT_COMMAND` in your configuration file to customize the sorting.  I'm not really familiar with Todo.txt or the MIT add-on, but that is probably where I'd start looking.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not at all familiar with how `export TODOTXT_SORT_COMMAND='env LC_COLLATE=C sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1n'` works...and even then it says after line number sorting in the comments in the config, so I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for even if I did.